# What is the main difference between HTTP request to a website VS HTTP request to the REST API?

Tags: api, rest, http, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to wrap my head around this and I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me.

What is the main difference between making a "HTTP GET" request to a webpage and fetching the HTML VS making "HTTP GET" request to a REST API endpoint and fetching JSON?

As far as I know, REST API can also return HTML, so in that case, what would be the main differentiator between these two?

I may be missing something obvious here but I am just trying to conceptualize each action so I have no more ambiguity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the main difference between making a "HTTP GET" request to a webpage and fetching the HTML VS making "HTTP GET" request to a REST API endpoint and fetching JSON?

Not much?

In the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) (which is followed by HTTP... [mostly](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3_4)).  an important constraint is [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5), which includes the idea that all resources understand all messages the same way.

That means we can do things like use a general purpose web browser to fetch documents, or a general purpose cache to store representations, without needing any special code to distinguish "web resources" from "api resources".

A "good" REST API looks like a machine readable web site.

The only difference that you *might* notice in some cases is that the hypermedia representations of resources might use some standardized format that isn't HTML.

Otherwise, they are the same thing - the main difference being that a "REST API" tends to have more resources that are expected to be changed by incoming requests, as opposed to a website which is designed more for reading than editing.  So PUT/POST/PATCH requests are more commonly used with API resources.